# Build playbook backup in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm quite new to Ansible and despite dozens of pages of documentation I've read, I can't solve the problem I'm facing by myself.

So the idea is like this: we have multiple dedicated servers containing KVM machines and we intend to do remote backup for almost all VMs, but we only backup certain files in the VM, we don't take complete snapshots.

The architecture I thought of in Ansible would be like this:

- We have a group called `[backup_servers]` in which we add those servers that have the necessary space to hold backups, not just VMs
- For the group above, we take each server separately and add a variable called `"backup_collection_list"` and add here the hostnames of the servers whose backups we want to store
- For each VM (or group of VMs) we configure a variable called `"backup_folder_list"` in which we explicitly say what we want to keep remotely

The problem I am facing is this.
How could I write a playbook in which I can iterate through each server that will store the backups and then check for each VM in the list of the current server if there are folders specified as the source, otherwise I will return an error message?

In short, I'm trying to run a certain task while accessing the variables of server[i].kvm[j]

Thanks!

Comment: There are actually many ways to achieve your goal: which one did you try already and what are the problems you are facing? Please [edit] your question and add a [mre]. Meanwhile there is IMO a major problem with your project: your goal is to plant a nail and you are asking a question about how to best do it with a screwdriver. Ansible is not a backup tool. It's purpose is to e.g. setup your backup servers or the VMs you later want to backup... Of course you can develop something to use it to make the backup itself but this is definitely not the best tool for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[backup_servers]
bck_01 ansible_host=10.1.0.17
bck_02 ansible_host=10.1.0.10

[clients]
cl_01 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
cl_02 ansible_host=10.1.0.62
cl_03 ansible_host=10.1.0.63
```

Declare the variables in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/backup_collection_lists.yml
backup_collection_lists:
  bck_01:
    - cl_01
    - cl_02
  bck_02:
    - cl_03

backup_collection_list: "{{ backup_collection_lists[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/backup_folder_lists.yml
backup_folder_lists:
  cl_01: [/etc, /var, /tmp]
  cl_02: [/etc, /var, /tmp]
  cl_03: [/etc, /var, /tmp, /undef]
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: backup_servers

  vars:

    folders: "{{ dict(backup_collection_list|
                      zip(backup_collection_list|
                          map('extract', backup_folder_lists))) }}"

    results: "{{ find_out.results|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: '[].{client: item[0].key, path: item[1], isdir: stat.isdir}'

  tasks:

    - stat:
        path: "{{ item.1 }}"
      register: find_out
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ folders|dict2items }}"
        - value
      delegate_to: "{{ item.0.key }}"

    - debug:
        var: results|to_yaml

    - assert:
        that: "{{ results|rejectattr('isdir')|length == 0 }}"
        fail_msg: |
          Missing dirs:
          {{ results|rejectattr('isdir') }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => 
  results|to_yaml: |-
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
ok: [bck_02] => 
  results|to_yaml: |-
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: null, path: /undef}

TASK [assert] *********************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
fatal: [bck_02]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: |-
    Missing dirs:
    [{'client': 'cl_03', 'path': '/undef', 'isdir': None}]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: backup_servers

  vars:

    folders: "{{ dict(backup_collection_list|
                      zip(backup_collection_list|
                          map('extract', backup_folder_lists))) }}"

    results: "{{ find_out.results|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: '[].{client: item[0].key, path: item[1], isdir: stat.isdir}'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: folders|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ folders|dict2items }}"
        - value

    - stat:
        path: "{{ item.1 }}"
      register: find_out
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ folders|dict2items }}"
        - value
      delegate_to: "{{ item.0.key }}"

    - debug:
        var: find_out
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: results|to_yaml

    - assert:
        that: "{{ results|rejectattr('isdir')|length == 0 }}"
        fail_msg: |
          Missing dirs:
          {{ results|rejectattr('isdir') }}
```

```yaml
PLAY [backup_servers] *************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => 
  folders|to_yaml: |-
    cl_01: [/etc, /var, /tmp]
    cl_02: [/etc, /var, /tmp]
ok: [bck_02] => 
  folders|to_yaml: |-
    cl_03: [/etc, /var, /tmp, /undef]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/etc']) => 
  msg: cl_01 /etc
ok: [bck_02] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/etc']) => 
  msg: cl_03 /etc
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/var']) => 
  msg: cl_01 /var
ok: [bck_02] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/var']) => 
  msg: cl_03 /var
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/tmp']) => 
  msg: cl_01 /tmp
ok: [bck_02] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/tmp']) => 
  msg: cl_03 /tmp
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/etc']) => 
  msg: cl_02 /etc
ok: [bck_02] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/undef']) => 
  msg: cl_03 /undef
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/var']) => 
  msg: cl_02 /var
ok: [bck_01] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/tmp']) => 
  msg: cl_02 /tmp

TASK [stat] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [bck_02 -> cl_03(10.1.0.63)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/etc'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_01(10.1.0.61)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/etc'])
ok: [bck_02 -> cl_03(10.1.0.63)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/var'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_01(10.1.0.61)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/var'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_01(10.1.0.61)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_01'}, '/tmp'])
ok: [bck_02 -> cl_03(10.1.0.63)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/tmp'])
ok: [bck_02 -> cl_03(10.1.0.63)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_03'}, '/undef'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_02(10.1.0.62)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/etc'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_02(10.1.0.62)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/var'])
ok: [bck_01 -> cl_02(10.1.0.62)] => (item=[{'key': 'cl_02'}, '/tmp'])

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [bck_01]
skipping: [bck_02]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => 
  results|to_yaml: |-
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_01, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_02, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
ok: [bck_02] => 
  results|to_yaml: |-
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /etc}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /var}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: true, path: /tmp}
    - {client: cl_03, isdir: null, path: /undef}

TASK [assert] *********************************************************************************
ok: [bck_01] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
fatal: [bck_02]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: |-
    Missing dirs:
    [{'client': 'cl_03', 'path': '/undef', 'isdir': None}]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
bck_01: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
bck_02: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```